# ROLLO : security bits parameters

Tags: security-definition

In [ROLLO -Rank-Ouroboros, LAKE & LOCKER](https://pqc-rollo.org/doc/rollo-specification_2020-04-21.pdf)  p.20, it says that "Notice that for 128 security bits parameters, the practical security is rather higher than 128 at about 170 bits." How Can I calculate this size?

Comment: In other words, they claim the if one uses 170 bits then they will have security higher than 128.

Comment: @kelalaka,170 bits refers to the sum of bits of q,n,m,r,d?

Comment: It seems so. One has to go deeper. You can ask the authors, too. If got a response, write an answer and poke me, too.